# Modal in each carousel slide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

IM trying(failing) to make a pop-up window(Continue reading button) in each of 5 carousel slides. I am using Glide.js. I found a way to do that in one slide with

```
const modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName('myBtn');
const span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];


btn.onclick = function() {
    $('.modal').fadeIn();
};

span.onclick = function() {
    $('.modal').fadeOut();
};


window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        $('.modal').fadeOut();
    };
};
```

and there's is some Html for modal box

---

```html
<div>
  <button class="myBtn">Continue Reading</button>
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>TEXT</p>
    <div id="modal-avatar" class="avatar">
    <img src="img\Avatar.png">
    <p>Text<br><span>text</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to make 3 arrays and work with them, but I got in over my head, if someone could give me a hint on how to accomplish this without repetitive code I would be grateful.

Comment: Is your button class="myBut" meant to be class="myBtn"?

Comment: Adding to @MhluziBhaka, assuming that is a misspelling then you also need to add [0] so it becomes: `const btn = document.getElementsByClassName('myBtn')[0];` or just use `const btn = document.querySelector('.myBtn');`

Comment: @ Mhluzi Bhaka  Yes, misspelled it along the way, sry.

Comment: @ imvain2  The js code above worked with 1 slide having modal box code. At the very beginning, "myBtn" was an id, not class and js code for it was const btn = document.getElementById('myBtn').